# In the following computation expression, for/while do not loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, f#, computation-expression

I have the following computation expression. The problem is that For/While do not loop.

```
type Internal<'T> = Internal of option<'T>
type Maybe<'T>    = Maybe    of Lazy< Internal<'T> >
type Delayed<'T>  = Delayed  of (unit -> Internal<'T>)

let run (Maybe f) = f.Force()

type MaybeBuilder() = 
    member this.Bind(m, f) = m |> bind f
    member this.Return(x) = Internal (Some x)
    member this.ReturnFrom(Maybe v) = v.Force()
    member this.Zero() = Internal None
    member this.Combine(a, g) = a |> combine g
    member this.Delay(f) = f |> delay 
    member this.Run(f) = f |> run 
    member this.While(guard, Delayed body) =
        if not ( guard() ) then this.Zero()
        else ( body() ) |> bind ( fun () -> this.While(guard, Delayed body) ) 
    member this.TryWith(Delayed body, handler) =
        try this.ReturnFrom( Maybe ( lazy body() ) )
        with e -> e |> handler 
    member this.TryFinally(Delayed body, compensation) = 
        try this.ReturnFrom( Maybe ( lazy body() ) )
        finally compensation()
    member this.Using(disposable : #System.IDisposable, body) =
        let body' = fun () -> disposable |> body 
        this.TryFinally( Delayed body', fun () ->
            match disposable with 
            | null -> ()
            | disp -> disp.Dispose() )
    member this.For(sequence : #seq<_>, body) =
        let sequence' = sequence |> seq 
        this.Using( sequence'.GetEnumerator(), fun enum -> 
            this.While( enum.MoveNext, this.Delay( fun () -> enum.Current |> body ) ) )
```

I am not certain whether this is a "Combine" issue or what and I do appreciate the help.
The Helper functions are defined inside the MaybeBuilder type:

```
let bind (f : 'T -> Internal<'U>) (Internal m) =
    match m with
    | None -> Internal None
    | Some x -> x |> f
let combine (Delayed g) (Internal m) =
    match m with 
    | Some _ -> Internal m
    | None   -> g()
let delay f = Delayed f    
let run (Delayed f) =
    let (Internal runResult) = f()
    Maybe (lazy Internal runResult)
```

As an example, the following code produces "j is 1" and that is it.

```
let maybe = new MaybeBuilder()    

let m7 : Maybe<int> =
    maybe {
        let sequence = seq [ 1 .. 13 ]
        for j in sequence do 
            printfn "j is %i" j  
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "do not loop"?

Comment: Just updated with an example ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, changing the definition of "While" to the following seems to have solved the issue.

```
    member this.While(guard, Delayed body) =
        if not ( guard() ) then this.Zero()
        else body() |> combine ( Delayed ( fun () -> this.While(guard, Delayed body) ) )
```

Comment: Though it seems a bit odd as apparently the standard definition utilises "Bind".